# He looked very impressed with/by it?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> She showed him a painting of hers and he looked very impressed **with/by**
>   it.

Are both grammatically correct? Which one would you use?

Comment: Welcome to ELL!   Have you done any research on this question?  Please share what you found and what confused you.   I did a quick check of the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/impress) and the answer seems pretty clear -- please share more details with us so we can understand how to help you.  Thanks and keep contributing!  Please read the [New Contributor's Guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/) and [**"Details, Please"**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/). **Welcome!**

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct because the verb *impressed* is followed by *with* or
*by*.

So you can say:

> He looked very impressed **with** it.

or

> He looked very impressed **by** it.

Comment: You might want to set those sentences off with bolding/italics and punctuation.